# Py2Exe variables.py file

Tags: python, compilation, py2exe

I am trying to compile my script using Py2Exe. This is the setup.py file. As you can see, I have put the data_files as 'variables.py' and the file which turns into an exe is 'Autoreply_SOURCE.py'

```
import py2exe
import certifi
print ("Location", certifi.where())
from distutils.core import setup

Mydata_files = ['cacert.pem', 'variables.py']

setup(
    console=['Autoreply_SOURCE.py'],
    data_files= Mydata_files,
    options={
            "py2exe":{
                    "packages": ["tweepy", "json", "winsound",],
                    "bundle_files": 1,
                    "compressed": True,
            }
    }
)
```

This works fine, as in the variables.py is run and the .exe is executed but its values are frozen after it's been compiled. Is there a way to overcome this? A user should be able to run the main script but able to change variables.py.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `import variables` in `Autoreply_SOURCE.py` the file `variables.py` will be compiled and will be added to the zipfile as a module (if you open `library.zip` you will see `variables.pyc` inside), so you may not change its content after compiling. As you said, "the values are frozen", and you don't have any possibility to change this behavior.

What you could do instead is replacing the import statement and import the module dynamically in a very hackish and not recommended way. I mean this:

```
# import variables (delete or comment this line)
with open('variables.py') as module:
    exec(module.read())
```

**Note that doing this and allowing the user to edit `variables.py` could be very risky and not recommended** because the code will be executed, so I would suggest you to afford this problem in a different way. One easy option is to create a config file (it could be in JSON format or any other) and load from it only the specific values that you want the user to edit.

For example:

```
import json

with open('config.json') as config_file:
    user_data = json.load(config_file)
```